# Vb.Net 2D Dictionary - very slow

Tags: vb.net

I need to create a 2D dictionary/keyvalue pair.
I tried something like this.

[image]

```
Dim TwoDimData As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))

'Create an empty table
For Each aid In AIDList   '(contains 15000 elements)
    TwoDimData.Add(aid, New Dictionary(Of String, String))
    For Each bid In BIDList   'contains 30 elements
        TwoDimData.Item(aid).Add(bid, "")
    Next
Next

'Later populate values.
[some code here to populate the table]

'Now access the value
'The idea is to access the info as given below (access by row name & col name)
 Msgbox TwoDimData.Item("A004").Item("B005")   ' should give the value of 2
 Msgbox TwoDimData.Item("A008").Item("B002")   ' should return empty string. No error
```

**Issue:**

The issue is in Creating the empty table. It takes 70 seconds to create the TwoDimData table with empty values. Everything else seems to be fine. Is there any way to improve the performance - may be instead of using Dictionary?

Comment: Something weird is going on here. I ran your code and the code took my computer around 85ms. Your code is running 823x slower. What else are you doing?

Comment: @Enigmativity, how did you try? Can you please show how you did. For me everythign else works really great. Except that `'Create an empty table` takes >68 seconds. not really sure whats going on.

Comment: Take a look at this code - https://dotnetfiddle.net/8KuSGy - it runs for me in LINQPad in approx 85ms. It won't run on dotnetfiddle as-is due to using too much memory.

Comment: oh man...your example helped me to correct the issue. You are awesome. I i' ll upvote some of ur answers in return :)

Comment: How did it help? It was basically the same code you had in your question.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I know...the thing is `AIDList` was not a list. instead it was a just a query expression. This `For Each aid In AIDList` made the query execute again and again. Your example helped me to remind that to correct it. Thanks for your time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try `Dictionary(Of Tuple(Of String, String), String)` instead. That is, the keys are pairs of strings (`Tuple(Of String, String)`) and the values are strings. That would appear to correspond nicely to the diagram in your question.

```
Dim matrix As New Dictionary(Of Tuple(Of String, String), String)

' Add a value to the matrix:
matrix.Add(Tuple.Create("A003", "B004"), "3")

' Retrieve a value from the matrix:
Dim valueAtA003B004 = matrix(Tuple.Create("A003", "B004"))
```

Of course you can define your own key type (representing a combination of two strings) if [`Tuple(Of String, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) seems too generic for your taste.

Alternatively, you could also just use (possibly [jagged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkhhsz9t.aspx)) 2D arrays, but that would potentially waste a lot of space if your data is [sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array) (i.e. if there are many empty cells in that 2D matrix); and you'd be forced to use numeric indices instead of strings.

**P.S.:** Actually, consider changing the dictionary value type from `String` to `Integer`; your example matrix suggests that it contains only integer numbers, so it might not make sense to store them as strings.

**P.P.S.:** Do *not* add values for the "empty" cells to the dictionary. That would be very wasteful. Instead, instead of simply retrieving a value from the dictionary, you check whether the dictionary contains the key:

```
Dim valueA As String = ""  ' the default value
If matrix.TryGetValue(Tuple.Create("A007", "B002"), valueA) Then
    ' the given key was present, and the associated value has been retrieved
    …
End If
```

Comment: It takes 69 seconds consistently now with Tuple.

Comment: It was a stupid issue i had made. Thanks for your time. plus 1.

Comment: 69 seconds (instead of 70 seconds) is not much of an improvement...?

Comment: I need empty values for my requirement as I need to create a table like matrix. When i used dictionary (wrong logic) - the  performance was between 68-71 seconds. Tuple was 69 seconds continuously (with same wrong logic). I dont see any performance improvement with Tuple. But have you ever experimented with Dictionary & tuple? Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that a simple structure would suffice for this?

```
Public Structure My2DItem
  Public Row As Integer
  Public Col As Integer
  Public Value As String
End Structure

Public My2DArray As Generic.List(Of My2DItem) = Nothing
Public Size As Integer
Public MaxRows As Integer
Public MaxCols As Integer
'
Sub Initialise2DArray()
'
Dim CountX As Integer
Dim CountY As Integer
Dim Item As My2DItem
'
  'initialise
  MaxRows = 15000
  MaxCols = 30
  Size = MaxRows * MaxCols
  My2DArray = New Generic.List(Of My2DItem)
  '   
  'Create an empty table
  For CountY = 1 To 15000
    For CountX = 1 To 30
      Item = New My2DItem
      Item.Row = CountY
      Item.Col = CountX
      Item.Value = "0"
      My2DArray.Add(Item)
      Item = Nothing
    Next
  Next
'
End Sub
```

And to read the data out of the array,

```
Function GetValue(Y As Integer, X As Integer) As String
'
Dim counter As Integer
'
GetValue = "Error!"
If My2DArray.Count > 0 Then
  For counter = 0 To My2DArray.Count - 1
    If My2DArray(counter).Row = Y Then
      If My2DArray(counter).Col = X Then
        GetValue = My2DArray(counter).Value
        Exit Function
      End If
    End If
  Next
End If
'
End Function
```

And to read your sample cell A004 B005

```
MyStringValue = GetValue(4,5)
```

Comment: It was a stupid issue i had made. Thanks for your time. plus 1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a class that has properties for the AID and BID and use this as the basis for the values you want to store

```
Public Class AIdBId
    Public Property AId As Integer
    Public Property BId As Integer
    Public Sub New(aId As Integer, bId As Integer)
        Me.AId = aid
        Me.BId = bid
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note that I have used integers for everything because it seems that is all you need and it is more efficient that using a string

Then you can add values where they are non-zero:

```
'define your dictionary
Dim valueMatrix As New Dictionary(Of AIdBId, Integer)

'add your values
valueMatrix.Add(New AIdBId(1, 1), 1)
valueMatrix.Add(New AIdBId(2, 3), 1)
valueMatrix.Add(New AIdBId(4, 3), 3)
valueMatrix.Add(New AIdBId(5, 8), 8)

'check if a value exixts
Dim valueExixsts As Boolean = valueMatrix.ContainsKey(New AIdBId(9, 9))

'get a value
Dim i As Integer = valueMatrix(New AIdBId(4, 3))
```

So you can now combine these two to return the value if there is one or zero if not:

```
 Private Function GetValue(valuematrix As Dictionary(Of AIdBId, Integer), aId As Integer, bId As Integer) As Integer
    Dim xRef As New AIdBId(aId, bId)
    If valuematrix.ContainsKey(xRef) Then
        Return valuematrix(xRef)
    Else
        Return 0
    End If
End Function
```